# Android Runtime GPS Location - Blackberry Device - not working

Tags: android, gps, blackberry-eclipse-plugin, blackberry-10

My app has been ported from Android to blackberry and it works fine...

the only thing not working is the GPS location which works on the android....

the app displays a message to the using that we are trying to find the location and if no location is found we tell the user that we could not retrieve a location..

here is the code

```
private void gpsLocation()
   {
         //Get the location manager
         locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
         //Provide Criteria
          Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
         provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
          Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

         locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 400, 1, this);

         if(location != null){

                 onLocationChanged(location);
          } else{
                 Log.i(TAG, "no GPS location available - waiting for GPS fix");

                 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.gpsWaitingToast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                if (Debug.GPS_USE_MONTREAL) {
                      currentLatitude = Double.valueOf(Debug.GPS_LAT_MONTREAL); currentLongitude = Double.valueOf(Debug.GPS_LNG_MONTREAL); // montreal
                 }
                 waitForGpsFix(GPSFIX_DELAY);
          }
```

its not working,, I restarted the app ,, did it next to a window and all that stuff..

nothing works..

your advise and help is greatly appreciated.

Regards

Comment: It works well using GPS provider, but it doesn't work using Network provider.

Comment: How do I change it in my code?

Answer (score 1):

There was previously a bug where `LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER` returned null, which may still be returned by the `locationManager.getBestProvider()` method. This should be fixed in the newer OS builds, however.

If you'd like to fix your code immediately, all you would need to do would be to set:

```
provider = LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER
```

as in the early stages, `GPS_PROVIDER` was the only provider that was implemented in the player.