# Porting Android app to run on BlackBerry 10 Android runtime - Email & Photos

Tags: android, blackberry, blackberry-10

I'm porting an app from Android to Blackberry.

I've found some [limitations](http://developer.blackberry.com/android/apisupport/)...

I'm using Google Maps, but as I read, we can use an WebView with Google Maps, as pointed [here](http://developer.blackberry.com/android/apisupport/apisupport_mapping_support.html)  to overcome this.

-Questions related: [Q1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14648231/porting-android-app-to-run-on-blackberry-10-android-runtime-google-maps?rq=1), [Q2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15550521/android-runtime-gps-location-blackberry-device-not-working?rq=1)

---

**Sharing**

I also share image and text on Android to Facebook, Twitter and Email using the ShareActionProvider (http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/shareaction.html).

Is it possible for an Android App ported to BlackBerry 10 to use something to replace this?

I was thinking about using Facebook SDK and Twitter SDK to replaced Share to those two, but what about Email?

I've read [here](http://developer.blackberry.com/android/apisupport/unsupportedapi_blackberry10_intents.html) that ACTION_SEND is also unavailable. So how can we send an email for example from an app?

---

**Camera**

Also is it possible to take a picture or access the gallery to get one? I did not found anything about this.

Comment: Before you start working too much on this, look at the Android Roadmap: http://developer.blackberry.com/android/tools/roadmap/.  There is a lot happening in 10.2.1, including MapView, and from what I have heard, it is not too far away.  So rather than work hard on swapping things, I would see what 10.2.1 offers you.  Look here too: http://developer.blackberry.com/android/apisupport/unsupported_api_jellybean_intents.html

Comment: Thanks for the very useful tip. I've seen they are porting the Google Maps v1, I'm using the v2 :-\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I've read here that ACTION_SEND is also unavailable. So how can we
>   send an email for example from an app?

The linked page said that *"Android applications cannot provide system-wide services to the rest of the device"* for those Intents. This is if your app want to be a provider for those actions.

If I understand you correctly, you wanted instead to use that Intent to send out something from your app, right? I believe it should be supported, but I haven't tried it myself.

> Also is it possible to take a picture or access the gallery to get
>   one? I did not found anything about this.

The camera is supported quite well from what I have a chance to test out.

Using [`MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html#ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE) and accessing the Android [`Camera`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html) API directly works fine for me.